# In Shiny, select a salectInput choices by source() an .R document but dependent on the choices of another selectInput choices

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to change the choices of a salectInput by sourcing (source()) an .R document but dependent on the choices of another selectInput.

I have tried different options and read similar post but I do not get it working.

I included a very simple UI with a code I originally thought would work.

For this code the error is: Error in hasGroups(choices) : object 'input' not found

Thanks very much in advance for the insights.

```
library(shiny)


ui <- # Define UI for dataset viewer application

  shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

    headerPanel("Input Choices"),  

    sidebarPanel(

      selectInput(inputId = "Year", "Choose a Year:", 

                  choices = c("2012", "2011")),

      selectInput(inputId = "Cat", "Choose a Category:",   
                  choices =
                    if(input$Year == "2011") {
                    source("./Choices/Choices_OpB.R")
                    } else if (input$Year == "2012"){
                      source("./Choices/Choices_OpA.R")
                    }
                  ),    width = 2),


    mainPanel(

      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", 

                  tabPanel("Html Pages")), width = 10)

  ))

#


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Choices_OpB.R would be:

```
c("D", "E", "F")
```

Choices_OpA.R would be:

```
c("A", "B", "C")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. To change the options we'll need to do it in the server part of the code, not the UI. The updateSelectInput function can do it for us:

```
library(shiny)


ui <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

    headerPanel("Input Choices"),

    sidebarPanel(

        selectInput(inputId = "Year", "Choose a Year:", choices = c("2012", "2011")),

        selectInput(inputId = "Cat", "Choose a Category:", choices = c("No Choices Yet"))

    ,width = 4),

    mainPanel(

        tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",

                    tabPanel("Html Pages")

        )

    , width = 8)

))


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    observeEvent(input$Year, {

        if(input$Year == '2011') {source("./Choices/Choices_OpB.R")}

        if(input$Year == '2012') {source("./Choices/Choices_OpA.R")}

        updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'Cat', label = "Choose a Category:", choices = loaded_choices)

    })

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

For simplicity I altered Choices_OpA.R and Choices_OpB.R to

```
loaded_choices <- c("A", "B", "C")
```

```
loaded_choices <- c("D", "E", "F")
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your time. This does what I needed. Best.